# SIGABRT error while using UITableView and storyBoard added to an Empty Application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableView to display data fetched from webservice.Fetching is done fine and displays data in console.However I am getting SIGABRT error.I have also added storyboard to empty application , if that is causing any problems here, I am not sure.What should be done here?

Here is the description : -

```
      -[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance             0xcb38930
 2014-06-17 13:25:06.961 SushrutTest[879:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]:    unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb38930'
  *** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a985e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0181b8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b35903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a8890b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a884ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   SushrutTest                         0x0000380e -[ListViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 334
6   UIKit                               0x0067cd2f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x0067ce03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
8   UIKit                               0x00661124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
9   UIKit                               0x006745a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
10  UIKit                               0x005f8dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182d81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
12  QuartzCore                          0x0452472a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
13  QuartzCore                          0x04518514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
14  QuartzCore                          0x04526b55 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 43
15  UIKit                               0x005eb7e6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 595
16  UIKit                               0x005eb58d -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded] + 74
17  UIKit                               0x006c75a4 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1062
18  UIKit                               0x006c67c6 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 176
19  UIKit                               0x006c49f5 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 429
20  UIKit                               0x008b3732 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 328
21  UIKit                               0x008b3a37 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 703
22  UIKit                               0x008b3a76 -[UINavigationTransitionView _navigationTransitionDidStop] + 55
23  UIKit                               0x005da81c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 267
24  UIKit                               0x005d9005 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 334
25  UIKit                               0x005ed866 +[UIView(Animation) commitAnimations] + 36
26  UIKit                               0x008b3535 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 2795
27  UIKit                               0x008b2a42 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 55
28  UIKit                               0x006c83d7 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3186
29  UIKit                               0x006c872c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
30  UIKit                               0x006c9349 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
31  UIKit                               0x0080239d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
32  UIKit                               0x005f8dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
33  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182d81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
34  QuartzCore                          0x0452472a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
35  QuartzCore                          0x04518514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
36  QuartzCore                          0x04524675 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
37  UIKit                               0x006b3ca3 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
38  UIKit                               0x005d2d27 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
39  UIKit                               0x005d18c6 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
40  UIKit                               0x005d1798 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
41  UIKit                               0x005d1820 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
42  UIKit                               0x005d08ba __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
43  UIKit                               0x005d081c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
44  UIKit                               0x005d1573 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
45  UIKit                               0x005d4b66 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
46  UIKit                               0x006a5dc7 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
47  UIKit                               0x005ca7cc -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
48  UIKit                               0x005ca947 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
49  UIKit                               0x005cabdd -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
50  UIKit                               0x005d544a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
51  UIKit                               0x005888e0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
52  UIKit                               0x0058cfb8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
53  UIKit                               0x005a142c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
54  UIKit                               0x005a1999 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
55  UIKit                               0x0058ec35 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
56  GraphicsServices                    0x038a82eb _PurpleEventCallback + 776
57  GraphicsServices                    0x038a7df6 PurpleEventCallback + 46
58  CoreFoundation                      0x01a13dd5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
59  CoreFoundation                      0x01a13b0b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
60  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3e7ec __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
61  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3db33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
62  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3d94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
63  UIKit                               0x0058c6ed -[UIApplication _run] + 840
64  UIKit                               0x0058e94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
65  SushrutTest                         0x00003b2d main + 141
66  libdyld.dylib                       0x020d4725 start + 0

   )
      libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Probably you get a JSON response from the server, which you parse some way to Objective C objects, but the parsed object is an NSDictionary, you have to get the array you want which is probably an object for a key in that dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   -[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance             0xcb38930
> ```

You are asking -objectAtIndex: from an object that is an NSDictionary in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

NSDictionary doesn't know -objectAtIndex - but NSArray does. So somehow you get a dictionary when what you want is an array.

Show the contents of cellForRowAtIndexPath for further hints.

Answer (score 0):

You are confuse NSDictonary and NSArray objects. As noted in message NSDictonary don't have 
objectAtIndex selector.